# MAPLE: Solve Equation with 3 unknowns in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, maple

I am trying to input in MAPLE

```
solve(23x+15y+18z = 11780, {x,y,z})
```

And it returns

```
{x=x, y = -23/15 x +2356/3 -6/5 z, z=z}
```

But I want it better to return something like

```
{x = 211 ,y = 223, z = 199}
```

How can I achieve to have the result in Relatives.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, the problem is that the equation has infinitely many solutions. Which one of them do you want? Also, what do you mean by "have the result in relatives"?

Comment: The smallest one, 
or I rather have a Set of different solutions than doing the calculation

Comment: Well, you **do** have a set of different solutions, that's what MAPLE gave to you. In order to generate a solution, you can set $x=x_0$ (any number you like) and $z=z_0$ (also any number you like). Now $y$ is given by
$$
y= -\frac{23}{15}x_0 + \frac{2356}{3} - \frac{6}{5}z_0
$$
Because the solution can be interpreted as an infinite line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there is no smallest value.

Comment: There could be a "solve the solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the fewest prime factors for each unknowns."
The solution given by Maple is unpraticable

Comment: tray isolve(23*x+15*y+18*z = 11780)

Comment: Aleksas is right.  `solve` is for all solutions, `isolve` is for integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If "the smallest one" means the one that minimizes $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, you could try

```
> extrema(x^2+y^2+z^2,{23*x+15*y+18*z=11780},{x,y,z},p);
```

$$\frac{69384200}{539}$$

```
> p;
```

$$ \left\{  \left\{ x={\frac{135470}{539}},y={\frac{88350}{539}},z={
\frac{106020}{539}} \right\}  \right\} 
$$